# Why is the Rails legacy route match not recommended?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The default route file has the following segment:

```
  # This is a legacy wild controller route that's not recommended for RESTful applications.
  # Note: This route will make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests.
  # match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
```

So what exactly is the problem with letting Rails assume the controller, action, and view to display when the format is ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)' ? I mean, for more specific things like nesting I can always use specific routes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If developers are allowed to being lazy, they will be. We are super great at optimizing efforts.

Not being explicit about routes may help you save 5 seconds each time you have a new controller, but it will be a headache for new developers, which will be unfamiliar with your codebase and hence don't know how things are glued. They will have to reverse engineer your views-controllers.

Being there. Not pretty.

Being explicit is usually better.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a common-sense security measure.

It forces the designer to whitelist GET requests so that the app does not inadvertently divulge the contents of a table or record to a malicious user.

Answer (score 1):

Because not everyone is building the next Facebook and some of us do this for fun or to make simple apps that we use only on our development device or to simply not be a ass and "answer" a question with that actually has an answer, instead of make ourselves look uber smart and important:

```
match '/:controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)', to: "#{:controller}#{:action}", via: [:get, :post]
```